# Selenium Python check if div exist

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm **scraping** facebook post, I'm using

`status = x.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='_5pbx userContent _3576']/p[1]").text`

for getting status post, and html structure of facebook post like here

```
<div class="_5pbx userContent _3576" data-ft="{{"tn":"K"}}" id="js_33">
  <p>Bersama Ketua APTIKOM Yogyakarta, Bapak Dr. Agfianto Eko Putra, M.Si. @agfi68<br> Terima kasih banyak telah memesan buku Digital.Is. Me</p>
</div>
```

sometimes, p tag inside div, but sometime not inside div

how can I create status = x.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='_5pbx userContent _3576']/p[1]").text

that support if inside div or not inside div

Comment: Do you mean, some `_5pbx userContent _3576` divs does not have the `p`?  Why don't you use the `.getAttribute("innerText")` on the div itself, which will give the innertext if `p` exist, otherwise it will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a 
`x.find_elements_by_xpath`
 and see if the length is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='_5pbx userContent _3576']")` to find the `<div>` element.

Then you can inspect that element to see whether or not it has a `<p>` child element.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select two different elements depending on certain conditions. So, you should use:

```
.//div[@class='_5pbx userContent _3576'][not(p[1])]|.//div[@class='_5pbx userContent _3576']/p[1]
```

In general, assuming variables `$XPathExpression1`, `$XPathExpression2` and `$Condition` :

```
$XPathExpression1[$Condition]|$XPathExpression2[not($Condition)]
```